# Error 403 GitBash

Tags: git, git-bash

estoy con GitBash y tengo un problema que me esta molestando bastante.

Intento subir datos a mi repositorio con git push y no me deja subir nada, me dice permiso denegado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado cambiar el "origin" y está correcto, pienso que puede ser cuestión de usuario y contraseña, ya que la contraseña no me la pide en ningun momento.

Comment: intentaste con `git push -u`?

Comment: Me sale lo mismo que con el git push asecas, no funciona

Comment: ejecuta `git config --list` para ver la configuracion de tu git

Answer (score 0):

Al final era que me había cambiado de cuenta de git y estaba intentando operar sobre la nueva.
El problema era que al reinstalar la aplicación entera aún perduraba esa cuenta y no sabía como eliminarla. 
Al final he borrado la cuenta para que se deslogee y me volviese a pedir usuario y contraseña.